# wordpress error ZipArchive is not installed on your server, but is required if you need to import demo content

Tags: wordpress, zip

I am setting up a new test Ubuntu 16.04 server with wordpress and avada.

The server is running php 7.0 and in the avada system status dialogue I am getting an error saying that ZipArchive is not installed on the server. However, I have installed php7.0-zip and php7.0-gd.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try reloading php.

```
sudo systemctl reload  php7.0 reload
```

or

```
sudo systemctl reload php7.0-fpm  # if you use php7.0-fpm mode
```

Comment: According to OP (I can see their deleted answer) restarting apache2 fixed it. Maybe you could add that as an additional suggestion?